# I am getting each minute data from sql query? I have the hours of data in database i want to take data for each 15th minute instead of each minute

Tags: mysql

I am using the query

```
SELECT GridPow
     , DATE_FORMAT(Time,'%H')
     , DATE_FORMAT(Time,'%i')
     , INVId 
  from KStar_Data 
 where Date=? 
   and SiteId=? 
   and INVId=? 
 order 
    by HOUR(Time)
     , MINUTE(Time);
```

How to get the data only for each 15min data.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to define which data you want to group each 15 minutes.

You can ask for this like:

```sql
    SELECT 
somefield, 
SUM(myfield) 
from mytable 
where some=thing 
    GROUP BY HOUR(Time), 
FLOOR(ROUND(MINUTE(Time)/15.5,1));
```

This way you get four groups depending on the minutes:

```
0: 0-14 min
1: 15-30 min 
2: 31-45 min 
3: 46-59 min
```

That's not fully accurated as you get two groups of 15 minutes, one of 16 minutes and one of 14 minutes, but it could do the trick. Or perhaps you can play with the 15.5 value to get a more accurated formula if you need exact 15 minutes each group.